# Is it possible to make a default-initialized class std::is_trivial for performance purposes

Tags: c++, templates, stl, c++17

When making simple pod-classes, it seems I have to make a choice between safety and performance. This happens as a result of that `std::is_trivial`, which is used in STL to determine if a class can be copied via `memmove`/`memcpy`, or resort to a loop.

The following snippet demonstrates the difference:

```
// A can be copied via memmove
struct A { int x; }; // x is left uninitialized
static_assert(std::is_trivial_v<A>);
static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable_v<A>);
auto copy_a(A* first, A* last, A* dst) { std::copy(first, last, dst); }

// B is prevented to be copied via memmove
struct B { int x{}; }; // x is initialized
static_assert(!std::is_trivial_v<B>);
static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable_v<B>); // true
auto copy_b(B* first, B* last, B* dst) { std::copy(first, last, dst); }
```

From my perspective, it seems to be that std::copy would do fine to just utilize `std::is_trivially_copyable<>` rather than `std::is_trivial`, but I suppose there are subtle reasons std::copy uses std::is_trivial.

However, is there any way to make a class default initialized, but still allow STL to optimize the copying?

*Notes:*

- GodBolt available at https://godbolt.org/z/6tejQj
- Resorting to manual use of std::memcpy is not an option

Comment: `is_trivially_copyable` should be sufficient. This is fixed in GCC trunk.

Comment: Thanks! It seems though clang still uses std::is_trivial :/

Answer (score 3):

This should not be necessary in your circumstance. TriviallyCopyable is sufficient to be able to memcpy an object, and it does not require trivially default constructible. This seems to be simply an over-zealous C++ implementation.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but it seems both gcc 8.2 and clang latest (as of compiler explorer) are over-zealous :/ (But as mentioned, gcc has relaxed it's constrictions in trunk)